# Fetch sub inner XML Tag values using Java in Groovy file

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to fetch xml tag values. Issue here is I have same tag in different inner tags. I want to fetch the  tag values which is under  tag. Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getResponse
        xmlns="http://bankBazaarService.icicibank.com">
        <getResult>
            <arrayOfContext>
                <item>
                    <errorCode></errorCode>
                    <errorDescription></errorDescription>
                </item>
            </arrayOfContext>
            <typeOfEmploymentDetails>
                <type></type>
                <companyName></companyName>
                <typeOfBusiness></typeOfBusiness>
            </typeOfEmploymentDetails>
            <getOffers>
                <item>
                    <offerId>1</offerId>                        
                </item>
                <item>
                    <offerId>2</offerId>
                </item>
            </getOffers>
            </getResult>
        </getResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code is

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;

    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( responseXML ) ) );
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nList.item(i);
        println element
        String offerUd = element.getElementsByTagName("offerId").item(0).textContent?:""
        println offerId
    }
```

Element prints as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><item>
                    <errorCode/>
                    <errorDescription/>
                </item>
```

I'm actually trying to fetch 
        
            1

So that I can get the values of the tag. i.e. offerId. Is there any issue in the code

Comment: Is that the full output? This doesn't appear to be vanilla Java, with the `println element` bits?

Comment: println I'm printing in a groovy file. Don't think about println. Please check the logic

Comment: This would partially make sense if this wasn't the full output - is there more?

Comment: @EvanKnowles.. No that's the output. You can try in your editor to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code, fixed the typos (`offerUd` --> `offerId`), made it into Java:

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException
{
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder;

  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXML)));
  NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
  for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
  {
    Element element = (Element) nList.item(i);
    println(element.toString());
    String offerUd = element.getElementsByTagName("offerId").item(0).getTextContent() != null ? element.getElementsByTagName("offerId").item(0).getTextContent() : "";
    println(offerUd);
  }
}

private void println(String t)
{
  System.out.println(t);
}
```

And I got a NullPointerException on getting item `0` of the `"offerId"` tags, because the first item in your XML does not have an `"offerId"` tag.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xml.ReadXML.test(ReadXML.java:75)
```

Update: here's working code. Get the `GetOffers` element first, then get the items beneath it.

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException
{
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder;

  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXML)));
  NodeList offersList = document.getElementsByTagName("getOffers");
  for (int j = 0; j < offersList.getLength(); j++)
  {
    Element offer = (Element) offersList.item(j);

    NodeList nList = offer.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
    {
      Element element = (Element) nList.item(i);

      String offerUd = element.getElementsByTagName("offerId").item(0).getTextContent() != null ? element.getElementsByTagName("offerId").item(0).getTextContent() : "";
      System.out.println(offerUd);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Haan. Thats what.. I want to extract those values. How could I? and one more thing... if I have "xsi:nil="true"" tag in that value.. I'm getting as "Namespace for prefix 'xsi' has not been declared"

Comment: I've updated with working Java code that retrieves the values. How would you have `xsi:nil="true"` in that value?

Comment: I missed one more tag in the question. " <iboc xsi:nil="true"/>" is one of the tag under "<item>" tag. Please add it under and test